# Querying an ordered list with OR or IN clause

Tags: query, order-by

I am querying `items` from a database and display it to the user. (in my example I'll use `contacts` in table `tContacts`.

The user selects a couple of `items` in an order he decides (the user can random pick the items, so no column can be specified to order).

In the application I have the id's of those `items` in an `ordered list`.

Currently I query more details for those objects `one-by-one`.

Is it possible to create a query with an "ordered list", which returns the `items` in the *same order*?

something like (yes, this is ugly - probably also hitting the max sql query size):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    --how to append this list...
    SELECT 0 as listIndex, * from tContacts where conIdContact = 13259;
    SELECT 1 as listIndex, * from tContacts where conIdContact = 12472;
    [...]
    SELECT 568 as listIndex, * from tContacts where conIdContact = 12422;
)
ORDER BY listIndex
```

- OR: do i have to keep querying `one-by-one`
- OR: does this need a temp table (insert id and priority), then query, then drop temp table again.
- OR: query a **`batch`** and reorder the items in application code
  (this might be slow due possibly large lists)

note: a database independent solution is preferred (mariadb / mysql, postgresql and h2 are considered to be used in production.

my temp table concept:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_OrderedContacts(
    listIndex INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    contactId INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO temp_OrderedContacts (listIndex, contactId)
VALUES (0,13259), (1,12472), (2,12422);

SELECT * FROM tContacts
JOIN temp_OrderedContacts ON (tContacts.conIdContact = temp_OrderedContacts.contactId)

DROP TABLE temp_OrderedContacts;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/1822

Comment: i just used the tablenames from our database (designed 25 years back) to be quicker in testing the query ;-) - i'm also not naming classes ClassXYZ, but sometimes variables make sense if they are named like what they contain (eg ui can have a Label and an Textfield for one property -> lblUsername and txtUsername are the two ui components that relate to the UserName-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Postgres solution would be to put all the IDs into an array, then use something like this:

```
select t.*, il.listindex
from contacts t
   join unnest(array[13259, 12472, ..., 12422]) with ordinality as il(id, listindex) 
     on t.conidcontact = il.id
order by il.listindex;
```

<sup>(The above is actually standard ANSI SQL - but to my knowledge only Postgres and HSQLDB support that)</sup>

The array could also be passed as a parameter in a prepared statement (or whatever the term for that is in the programming language you are using).

---

If you can build a dynamic query, another option would be to use a row value constructor:

```
select t.*, il.listindex
from contacts t
   join ( 
      values 
        (1, 13259), 
        (2, 12472),  
        ..... 
        (568, 12422)
  ) as il(listindex, id) on t.conidcontact = il.id
order by il.listindex;
```

<sup>(The above is 100% standard ANSI SQL)</sup>