# Improve query performance of subquery with MAX()

Tags: postgresql, index, join, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking to migrate our support database from MS SQL Server to Postgres and most of it has gone OK. However, some of the queries seem to be slower on PG than on the SQL Server.

We have a ticket table which has a related table assignments. In the assignment table (linked by `ticket_id`) we can make comments and assign the ticket to another group to work on the ticket. So to find out who currently has the ticket we need to get the last update for the ticket

```
Select tbltickets.ticketid, tbltickets.ticketsummary, ta2.*
from tblTickets 
Join (
   SELECT tblassignment.ticketid,
          max(tblassignment.allocationid) AS maxallocationid
   FROM tblassignment 
   join tbltickets on tblassignment.ticketid = tbltickets.ticketid
   GROUP BY tblassignment.ticketid) as ta on tbltickets.ticketid = ta.ticketid
join tblassignment ta2 on ta.maxallocationid = ta2.allocationid
where tbltickets.closed is NULL;
```

So it works but it slower than we would like circa 2seconds and will only get slower.

it is looking up the `maxallocationid` subquery that is taking the time at 1.5s as it is doing the calculation for all the assignments, not just the ones for the tickets we are interested in (e.g closed is NULL)

I can improve like this:

```
Select tbltickets.ticketid, tbltickets.ticketsummary, ta2.*
from tblTickets 
Join (
   SELECT tblassignment.ticketid,
          max(tblassignment.allocationid) AS maxallocationid
   FROM tblassignment 
   join tbltickets on tblassignment.ticketid = tbltickets.ticketid
   where tbltickets.closed is null
   GROUP BY tblassignment.ticketid) as ta on tbltickets.ticketid = ta.ticketid
join tblassignment ta2 on ta.maxallocationid = ta2.allocationid
where tbltickets.closed is NULL;
```

It now runs in 170 msec which is fine, but I cannot then use in a view to make it reusable with different criteria (or at least I don't know how).

Is there a way to allow for filtering the tickets, *then* look up `maxassignment` only on returned tickets, preferable without reorting to functions/stored procedures!

I have considered using a trigger to update the ticket table with info from the assignment, but do not want to go there if I can avoid it as I am not familiar with this!

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want a **(`LEFT`) `JOIN LATERAL`** - the standard SQL equivalent of (`OUTER`) `APPLY` in SQL Server, as a_horse called to mind:

```
SELECT t.ticketid, t.ticketsummary, ta2.*
FROM   tblTickets t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ta.allocationid
   FROM   tblassignment ta
   WHERE  ta.ticketid = t.ticketid
   ORDER  BY ta.allocationid DESC NULLS LAST  -- see below!
   LIMIT  1
   ) ta2 ON true
WHERE  t.closed is NULL;
```

The *`LEFT`* `JOIN` preserves rows from `tblTickets` without related rows in `tblassignment`. To eliminate those, use `JOIN` instead.

Be sure to have an index on `tblassignment (ticketid, allocationid DESC NULLS LAST)`.
Drop `NULLS LAST` in query and index if `allocationid` is defined `NOT NULL`. (Index and query must agree on this for the index to be applicable.)

You can add any predicates to filter rows from `tblTickets` before the greatest `allocationid` is looked up, only for qualifying rows. (Maybe add index-support for common predicates on `tblTickets` ...)

This query should be ***very*** fast.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)
- [SQL Server - conditional aggregation with correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36553037/939860)
- [Postgres analogue to CROSS APPLY in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473447/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)
- [MySQL: Get most recent record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523404/939860)

Comment: Brilliant Erwin, that has made such a difference, I also took the NULLS LAST off to see what difference that made and it was 5 times faster with it. I have never seen LATERAL or NULLS LAST before so thank you - some extra reading for me to do!

Comment: @RobertB: `lateral` is the equivalent in standard SQL to Microsoft's `apply`