# Naming conventions for views and materialized views: "*_v", "v_*", "*_mv", "mv_*" or none?

Tags: postgresql, view, best-practices, materialized-view, naming-convention

My view stores quality metrics for various gizmos<sup>1</sup> in the database. Today I designed it to be a view. In a few years, as we produce more gizmos, it may need to be changed to a materialized view.

I was thinking of naming the view either of these 3 ways:
`gizmo_quality_metrics`
`gizmo_quality_metrics_v`
`v_gizmo_quality_metrics`

Which one should I choose?

This may need to be renamed (or not) a few years later, when switching it to a materialized view:
`gizmo_quality_metrics`
`gizmo_quality_metrics_mv`
`mv_gizmo_quality_metrics`

From the way I worded the question, you get the idea that I favor keeping the same name (`gizmo_quality_metrics`), which is based on the data, and disregard the implementation (thus, no prefixes and extensions). However, I have seen all of the above naming conventions in practice, and I am wondering what is the most maintainable one for the long term.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am simplifying - of course, they are not gizmos. They are actually deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) molecules, if you really want to know. But this is irrelevant.

---

**[EDIT, Mar 18, 2022]**

Related question (thanks to *a_horse_with_no_name* for mentioning it!):
[Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/192715)
Note that I do not link to any one particular answer in that literal *wall* of answers, from high to low rep users. It is instructive to read a few, though.

Comment: Naming conventions are largely a question of taste and style. And opinion-based questions are not a suitable here. The one important thing is to stay consistent. An inconsistent naming convention is often worse than none at all. To give *my* opinion: don't add any prefix or suffix. Especially since you intent to switch later.

Comment: There you go. I also voted to close the question for said reason, no offense.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naming conventions are largely a question of taste and style.

The one important thing is to stay **consistent**. An inconsistent naming convention is often worse than none at all. To give my opinion: don't add any prefix or suffix. Especially since you intend to switch later.

And always stick to legal, lower-case names. So you never have to double-quote. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)